# Using contacts plugin in Phonegap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I want to use the contacts plugin as documented here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts on PhoneGap Build.

PhoneGap build [now supports plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-using) but unfortunately this one (provided by phonegap?) doesnt seem to be listed?

I have tried adding the settings as per the plugin document and submitting the app to phonegap build but it says that the plugin is not supported. It seems strange that 3rd party plugins are available to use, but not ones that seem to be part of core phonegap.

Is there anyway to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out.

If you need to use the built in features you can use a `feature` entry in the config.xml as per this document:
https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

You can then use the contacts API as per:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html